# How can I extract a GeoJSON from a MySQL database and show it in a map created with Leaflet?

Tags: mysql, leaflet

So I've been trying to practice the leaflet library, and I implemented a system that lets me make polygons on the map, and save them in a table in a MySQL database like GeoJSON, but now I want to take all the polygons I've made and show them in the map, but I don't know-how.

this is the code of a PHP file that shows the map, and I want to add the polygons I've made so far to visualize them on the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 100hw; height: 90vh; border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>    
<script>
    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib }),
            map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(4.639386, -74.082412), zoom: 6 }),
            drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
    L.control.layers({
        'osm': osm.addTo(map),
        "google": L.tileLayer('http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
            attribution: 'google'
        })
    }, { 'Pedidos': drawnItems }, { position: 'topleft', collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I don't really know how or where to start, the table has two columns, one named 'geojson' in which it's located the GeoJSON, and the other one has an id, I'm a noob but I've been trying to do it, so if someone can give me a hint, I would appreciate.

UPDATE

I solve it, I add this to the PHP file into the script.

```
<script>
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib }),
        map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(4.639386, -74.082412), zoom: 6 }),
        drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
L.control.layers({
    'osm': osm.addTo(map),
    "google": L.tileLayer('http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        attribution: 'google'
    })
}, { 'Pedidos': drawnItems }, { position: 'topleft', collapsed: false }).addTo(map);

<?php
$sql="SELECT geojson FROM poligono WHERE ent = '$entidad'";
$dat = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($dat))
    {
        $poligono = $consulta['geojson'];
        ?>L.geoJSON(<?php echo $poligono;?>).addTo(map);<?php
    }
?></script>
```

Comment: Nice having found the solution by yourself, and to share it! :-) Please consider posting it as an _answer_ below, and accepting it, so that people know your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add this after you add the map to your page like is shown above.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT geojson FROM poligono WHERE ent ='$entidad'";
$dat = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($dat))
    {
        $poligono = $consulta['geojson'];
        ?>L.geoJSON(<?php echo $poligono;?>).addTo(map);<?php
    }
?>
```

remember to change "$sql" to the direction in which is located your geojson, and to put in "$consulta['geojson']" instead of 'geojson' the name of the column in which is located the GeoJSON.